# not initiating another activity in listview click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

The is my code.I am here pupulating a list view with some array data.when I am hitting the list I can be able to detect it by using a Toast.But I can't able to call another activity.
in the place of Toast event.
    public class ListView extends ListActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.foodjoint, RESTAURANTS));

    android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myClickHandler();
        }
    });

    //      ListView restuList=ListView();

}

static final String[] RESTAURANTS = new String[] {
    "Restaurant 1", "Restaurant 2", "Restaurant 3", "Restaurant 4", "Restaurant 5",
    "Restaurant 6", "Restaurant 7", "Restaurant 8", "Restaurant 9", "Restaurant 10",
    "Restaurant 11", "Restaurant 12", "Restaurant 13", "Restaurant 14", "Restaurant 15"
};
public void myClickHandler() {
    finish();
    Intent gotoLIst=new Intent(ListView.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(gotoLIst);
}
```

and here is my XmL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/AliceBlue "
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" >
```

I need to call another activity @ listView onitemClick.

Actually I have used another activity which also use some list-view.and that activity contains some error.that's why it's not working. Thnx to Luksprog for helping me to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to `finish()` the current `Activity` after you start the new one:

```
public void myClickHandler() {
    Intent gotoLIst=new Intent(ListView.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(gotoLIst);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: so U wanna mean tht If I just call this methof after following ur editing then I can be able to call another method?ok lemme try

Comment: 04-09 17:00:10.168: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView                                           here is the exception

Comment: @kaushik Does the new activity `MenuActivity` has a `ListView` on which you set an `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: @kaushik If you use the same constructor for `ArrayAdapter` like you did in the first class then the `int` field(like `R.layout.foodjoint`) must point to a layout file that only contains a `TextView` and nothing else. If you want something besides that `TextView` there are other constructor to use.